# GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.files.insert failed with error: Bad Request

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, attachment

I'm trying to trigger a script to copy an attached excel file from a Gmail Email and copy it into a google sheets sheet. Any email with the tag "TO PROCESS" should be copied. I'm getting this error message:

```
GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.files.insert failed with error: Bad Request
```

This is error is occuring at the line:

```
var convertedSpreadsheetId = Drive.Files.insert({mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS}, xlsxBlob).id; //Converts Excel to "Google Sheet" in google drive and gets file Id
```

Full code below:

```
function emailTrigger() {

  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("TO PROCESS");

  if(label != null){
    var threads = label.getThreads();
    for (var i=0; i<threads.length; i++) {
      getExcelFile(threads[i]);
      //Process them in the order received
      threads[i].removeLabel(label);
    }
  }
}

function getExcelFile(thread) 
{
//Function to pull Weekly Schedule Excel file from Janettas email and update phone spreadsheet and calendar
  
  var messages = thread.getMessages(); //pulls messages in first thread
  var len = messages.length; //Gets number of messages in first thread
  var message = messages[len-1] //get first message in given thread
  var attachments = message.getAttachments(); // Get attachment of first message
  
  //Steps to process the attachement
  var xlsxBlob = attachments[0]; // Is supposes that attachments[0] is the blob of xlsx file.
  var convertedSpreadsheetId = Drive.Files.insert({mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS}, xlsxBlob).id; //Converts Excel to "Google Sheet" in google drive and gets file Id
  var filename = xlsxBlob.getName(); //gets the converted files file name
  var tabName = filename.substring(13).slice(0,filename.length-18); // process the filename string into just the date to be Tab Name
  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(convertedSpreadsheetId).getSheets()[0]; // Location of converted Excel file -> now google sheet
  }
```

Comment: Can I ask you about the mimeType of `xlsxBlob`?

Comment: Is it possible you are using the v3 API instead of the v2 API? v2 has insert, but v3 has create.

Comment: @Tanaike - I'm sorry I'm not sure what you need from me. I've taken this code from another forum post. In order to answer your question, what specifically do you want and where can I look to get it?

Comment: @MattWilbert - When looking in Advanced Google Services - Drive API is listed as v2. I think this is the API you are referring to.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In this case, I thought that when the mimeType of `xlsxBlob` is checked, it might be the reason of your issue. So I asked about it.

Comment: It looks to me like in v2 insert if you have mimeType set you also need to have set uploadType, and I don't see where you did that, I don't use v2 so I could be misunderstanding the docs.

Comment: Can you confirm the selected thread/message has an attachment? I test your code and everything worked as expected for me.

Comment: @Tanaike - I hope my response was not interpreted as hostile. That was not my intent. I have found error checking this code challenging as I am unfamiliar with the details. How can I check the mimeType of xlsxBlob so that I can give you that information? Sorry if this is unclear.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could understand about your replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. In order to retrieve the mimeType of `xlsxBlob`, please put `console.log(xlsxBlob.getContentType())` just after `var xlsxBlob = attachments[0];` and run the script. By this, you can see the mimeType of it at the log.

Comment: @Tanaike - console.log(xlsxBlob.getContentType()) returns the following:  application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, it was found that the mimeType of `xlsxBlob` is for XLSX data. When you run the script under this condition, the same error of `API call to drive.files.insert failed with error: Bad Request` occurred?

Comment: @ale13 - Thanks for the reply. Your query prompted me to try another email and look at the specifics of the email causing the error. It appears my code works well on many of the emails from other weeks. A closer inspection showed that a few emails have been forwarded with encryption. These emails are throwing errors. I will need to look into how to deal with encryption.

Comment: @Tanaike - thank you for your guidance. As I just stated im my response to ale13 his question led me to realize that a few emails (including the currently tested one) have encryption that was causing that error to be thrown. I appreciate you help and apologize for any time I've wasted.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm not sure about `encryption` in your situation. I'm glad that you found the reason of your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was occurring because the specific excel spreadsheet was encrypted. There were no issues with the code and it can be used as intended.